# Warning: componentWillReceiveProps is depreciated, need to find an alternative for this lifecycle method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my interface

```
    interface FloatingLabelState {
        paddingAnim: Animated.Value;
        opacityAnim: Animated.Value;
        useNativeDriver :boolean;
    }
```

This is my componentWillReceiveProps function

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps: FloatingLabelProps) {
        Animated.timing(this.state.paddingAnim, {
            toValue: newProps.visible ? 5 : 9,
            duration: 230,
            useNativeDriver:this.state.useNativeDriver
        }).start();
        return Animated.timing(this.state.opacityAnim, {
            toValue: newProps.visible ? 1 : 0,
            duration: 230,
            useNativeDriver:this.state.useNativeDriver
        }).start();
    }
```

With many resources, came to know that static getDerivedStateFromProps() would be an alternative, Can someone help me convert componentWillReceiveProps to getDerivedStateFromProps method.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.